# How do I find my Windows partition?

Tags: partitioning, windows

I was Windows user 5 hours ago, and I installed Ubuntu on my laptop. In Windows I created two partitions on my hard disk.

In the first one I installed Ubuntu 10.10, but now I can't find the second one where I keep all my music, files and other documents. I mounted the partition using "Disk Utility" but still I can't find it in my Home Folder.

Comment: Can you post the output of `sudo fdisk -l`?

Answer (score 1):

The partition should be visible in the left pane of Nautilus-the-file-browser, and also in the left pane of Open File dialogs.

If you click on it there, it'll be mounted in a directory under /media, as Dirk Hartzer Waldeck pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

It will be mounted under `/media`.
That is the folder media from the very top folder root `/`.
Your home folder will be `/home/yourusernamehere`.
So you need to go up two levels and find media there.